# get json frile from other servers and create case in sales force

Tags: api, rest, apex

I want to collect/get that JSON data from google cloud and create a case in salesforce.

I have tried using this class but not sure it is not working. How to get a .json file from another server and create case on salesforce.

Apex class:

```
    HttpResponse res=new HttpResponse();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();        
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint('https://console.cloud.google.com/');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    Http h = new Http();  
    res= h.send(req);
    system.debug('res::>'+res.getBody());  
    string result= res.getbody();
    wrapper = (IOT_CaseWrapper) JSON.deserializeStrict(res.getBody(), IOT_CaseWrapper.class);   
    system.JSONParser parser=JSON.createParser(result);
    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@The parser value is $$$$$$$ '+parser);
```